# Publishing editorial work on arXiv

Tags: paper-submission, editors, arxiv

I have made an edition of handwritten notes of a physicist X (of the past century). What's the best way to submit it to arXiv?

I have seen two examples of editorial work in arXiv:

1. On one hand, the submission is made by the editor and also as author (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02601)
2. On the other hand the submission is made by the editor but he puts the original author (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203).

I think the two are founded. But I would like to know what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

arXiv has [guidelines for how to publish a translation of someone else's work](https://arxiv.org/help/translations), and I assume this would be similar.

You, as editor, should submit with your name in the "Author" field, but include the original author's name in the title; e.g. "Lise Meitner's Notes on Uranium Decay".

Of course, there is a separate issue of making sure that either the copyright has expired, or that you have permission of the original author (or their estate), which is also mentioned on the link above.